# Use a border in xaml without shrinking the contents of the border

Tags: c#, xaml, border

I am using a border object in xaml with a large border thickness.  However need a way to prevent the contents of the border from shrinking when i increase the border thickness, I just want them to draw over it if they are near enough to the edge.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't place your content inside the border, place it "above" it instead:

```
<Grid>
  <Border BorderThickness="20"/>

  <OtherContent/>
</Grid>
```